# Help with regex with sed -i for a tampermonkey script

Tags: sed, regular-expression, git, hashsum

I'm writing a tampermonkey script, using git and jsdelivr to store and send it to the users.

For the jsdelivr to work correctly, i need to change the commit hash in the url.
`// @require         https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tunisiano187@2020072501/WME-send-to-slack/WMESTSData.user.js`

In this case the part to be replaced is 2020072501 (not currently a hash)

I have a variable containing the hash, but i need to find the sed -i command to make the change (the hash will be changed in the file)

i'm thinking to use sed -i for it, but it's not doing what i want.

I've tryied this (without var to start)

`sed -i "s/187@(.*)\/WME-/187@newhash\/WME-/g" WME-send-to-slack.user.js`

Do you have an idea of what's wrong?

here is an example of the hash : e7327fbef446fb70370bc123296ecef5cd71eb48

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed "s/187@[[:xdigit:]]*\/WME-/187@newhash\/WME-/g"`

If you need to use extended regular expressions, use `sed -r`.

Comment: Thank you, but that will only work if that are number, but the hash is a number no ?

Comment: `[:**x**digit:]` matches all the hex digits, which is exactly what hashes consist of.